# Iterate over list with indices in vavr

Tags: java, lambda, collections, foreach, vavr

I'm using collections from [vavr](http://www.vavr.io/) library.
I have a list of elements defined like this:

```
List<Integer> integers = List.of(1, 2, 3);
```

How to iterate over elements of the list and have an access to the indices at the same time? In Groovy there is a method `eachWithIndex`. I'm looking for something similar in `vavr`. I'd like to use it like this:

```
integers.eachWithIndex((int element, int index) -> {
     System.out.println("index = " + index + " element = " + element);
})
```

How can I achieve this in `vavr`?

Comment: Using an index with an iterator is an anti pattern? Why you need that in the first place?

Comment: Why you consider this as an antipattern?

Comment: First go and read about the `iterator` pattern that will give you the answer.

Comment: Even Kotlin which is more functional language has forEachIndexed method, so you think it's a designers' mistake?

Comment: I think a lot of people will read this as a Java question, when this is all about `vavr`.

Comment: @pheasant yes it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vavr has an API similar to Scala. The Vavr collections (aka traversables) have a method called `zipWithIndex()`. It returns a new collection, which consists of tuples of elements and indices.

Additionally, using an Iterator saves us new collection instances.

```java
final List<Integer> integers = List.of(1, 2, 3);

integers.iterator().zipWithIndex().forEach(t ->
    System.out.println("index = " + t._1 + " element = " + t._2)
);
```

<strike>However, I see that creating a new collection is not as efficient as the Kotlin solution, especially when all information is already in place (elements and indices). I like the idea of adding a new method `forEachWithIndex` to Vavr's collections that acts like in Kotlin.</strike>

**Update:** We could add `forEachWithIndex(ObjIntConsumer<? super T>)` to Vavr's `Traversable`. It is more than just a shortcut for `iterator().zipWithIndex().forEach(Consumer<Tuple2<T, Integer>>)` because it does not create `Tuple2` instances during iteration.

**Update:** I just [added forEachWithIndex](https://github.com/vavr-io/vavr/pull/2284) to Vavr. It will be included in the next release.

*Disclaimer: I'm the creator of Vavr.*

Comment: One could also do a `integers.iterator().zipWithIndex().forEach(..)` to skip creating a new collection, if it's just a one-shot iteration.

Comment: Nándor is right, in this context it is more useful because we perform side-effects and do not transform the collection. I will update the post accordingly.

Comment: Does it make sense to add a "filterWithIndex" as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you want access to the index, simply use normal for loop and `List.get(ix)`.

Comment: Thanks, I just fought that there is more functional, declarative way to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 0):

[JMPL](https://github.com/klappdev/jpml) is simple java library, which could emulate some of the features pattern matching, using Java 8 features.
   This library also support simple iterate over collection.

```
   Figure figure = new Rectangle();    

   foreach(listRectangles, (int w, int h) -> {
      System.out.println("square: " + (w * h));
   });
```